# Excel write, borders colour

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlwt

I have a style:

`style = xlwt.easyxf('font: bold off, color black; borders: left thin, right thin, top thin, bottom thin; pattern: pattern solid, fore_color white;')`

but I want to have borders in other colour, not black. But color is not a known attribute for borders. Is there any posibility to do that?

Comment: Excel's default border colour is not Light Gray. Excel displays a light gray border around cells when there is no border defined.

Comment: That's right, I just edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you require is (e.g. for red borders):

```
style = xlwt.easyxf('font: bold off, color black;\
                     borders: top_color red, bottom_color red, right_color red, left_color red,\
                              left thin, right thin, top thin, bottom thin;\
                     pattern: pattern solid, fore_color white;')
```

Have a look here for all the available style options:
http://pydoc.net/Python/xlwt/0.7.2/xlwt.Style/